Question about the status of my app and flutter_local_notifications
enter image description here
For every hour of those I launch a notification and using the method
Future scheduleNotification(int id, String title, String body, String payload,
    DateTime scheduleNotificationDateTime) async {
  const AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails =
      AndroidNotificationDetails('notifications_test',
          'Test notifications', //channel es el nombre id es identificador del channel al que pertenece la notificacion
          importance: Importance.max,
          priority: Priority.high);
  const DarwinNotificationDetails darwinNotificationDetails =
      DarwinNotificationDetails();

  return flutterLocalNotificacionsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
      id,
      title,
      body,
      tz.TZDateTime.from(scheduleNotificationDateTime, tz.local),
      const NotificationDetails(
          android: androidNotificationDetails, iOS: darwinNotificationDetails),
      uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
          UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime);
}

How can I make it so that every time the notification scheduled for those hours is launched, even if the app is in the foreground and background, it saves that those hours have passed to update the status of that timeline?
All I need to do is figure out a way to save that time to update that widget in my app but my brain has been stuck for days.
